# ForecastingError.NOT_ENOUGH_INVENTORY (DFP API Targeting)

Tags: google-dfp

I work on a web application that periodically updates ad targeting criteria of certain direct-sale and house ads via the PHP DFP API.

Some of the ads return an "overbook warning" from the API, and some of them do not. The problem is that when the warning exists, the API ignores the targeting updates. When the warning is not returned, the API updates are accepted.

I have looked at the ads in the DFP interface and I cannot determine why some of them are overbooked and some of them are not. How can I disable the overbook warning, either globally for our DFP account, or singly on specific ads, or what else can I do so that DFP honors the targeting updates in spite of this error?

This is an example of the specific error that stops targeting parameters from updating:

`[ForecastingError.NOT_ENOUGH_INVENTORY @ lineItem[0].id; trigger:'44551404']`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in the [DFP API Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/gpO9HHWnyVQ).

One can explicitly ignore this warning when setting targeting properties with their line item service.

```
$lineItem->setAllowOverbook(true);
$lineItem->setSkipInventoryCheck(true);
```